Mini circuit breaker has an LED on for U > 270V
Any idea what it means? It is an Eaton Moeller FL7 32 amps (from the electric company).
I recently extended the grounding cable for my electric system for the house and this popped on.


Extending ground cable should only bother it if you goofed up badly.  Contact electric company if it is theirs/supplied by them.

Picture reuploaded

Is this breaker old or new? I cannot find FL7's on Google, but I can find PFL7's, and the data sheet for one PFL7 https://datasheet.eaton.com/datasheet.php?model=165671&locale=ru_RU uses "U" apparently to refer to voltage. It also says the rated operating voltage is 230V. Could the circuit be higher than 270V? (U>270)

Thanks for the good photo. Please revise again to tell us where you are and exactly how you extended your ground. There's still not much to go on here.

It was not the grounding in cause. The electric company supplied higher voltage then usual.

The circuit breaker is eaton moeller. But the voltage led device is another add on. Did not find it anywhere. Does somebody know if it limits voltage surge? Do i need to proctive device?
